# JQuery Autocomplete inside RadWindow

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, telerik

I have Jquery Autocomplete, it's on loaded on user control, which on RadWindow on page.

When I remove RadWindow and place user control directly to page it works fine, when I've RadWindow and it's `VisibleOnPageLoad=true` on page load it works fine again, but when `VisibleOnPageLoad = false` and is by default and on some button's click I set `VisibleOnPageLoad=true` after page refresh JQuery Autocomplete doesn't work.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: could you post your javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [RadAutoCompleteBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox-overview.html) instead of jQuery autocomplete when using Telerik controls.

If you wanted to stick with the jQuery implementation the issue is most likely that the supporting jQuery plugin library isn't being loaded.  You may need to manually add a direct reference to it on the parent page:

```
<script src=".../jquery-autocomplete.js" />
```